# HTML5 Video Play with full width and a certain height

Tags: css, html, video

I want to add a video to my website with full width and a certain height. Not full screen. Like this http://codecanyon.net/item/easy-video-background/full_screen_preview/1365012

How can I do that? I would be glad if you could help.

```
<video autoplay="autoplay" loop muted onplaying="this.controls=false" volume="0">
  <source src="videos/20.mp4" type='video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"'>
  Video not supported. 
</video>
```

css

```
video 
 {
    min-width: 100%;
    height: 600px;
    width: 100%;
    right: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    position: absolute;
 }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a container with 100% width and xpx height along with overflow:hidden and inside that you put your video tag

```
#video-container {
overflow: hidden;
width: 100%;
height: 200px;
}
```

Edit:
Edited the fiddle with video positioning in case you dont want the crop to start exactly from the top.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pmpwreob/1/)

Comment: Thanks for this ;)